# Does Google ESP V2 support validating JWT in cookies?

Tags: jwt, authorization, openapi, google-cloud-endpoints, extensible-service-proxy

I am looking to validate JWT through cookies.
Currently using Extensible Service Proxy (ESP) V1 to validate JWT, which is retrieved through the Authorization header. I am planning to shift to cookies for enhanced security.

ESP V2 might support cookies in [x-google-jwt-locations](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#x-google-jwt-locations). The documentation doesn't specify it anywhere ([link](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-auth0)). I can see Cookies support in the code ([link](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/auth.proto#L80-L98)) but wanted to make sure it's supported before starting ESP V1 to V2 migration.

Before starting ESP V1 to V2 migration, wanted to be sure that cookies are supported in V2